# Deploying angular/express.js app to heroku

Tags: angular, express, heroku, package.json

When I deploy my app to heroku, the home page gives a 404 response. The app has a angular client folder and server folder with the following structure.
(https://i.stack.imgur.com/STCCc.png)
There are 3 package.jsons. One in the root:

```
{
  "name": "curriculum-novum",
  "version": "1.0.0",
  "description": "",
  "main": "server/server.js",
  "scripts": {
    "start": "node server/server.js",
    "develop": "concurrently \"cd server && npm run watch\" \"cd client && npm start\"",
    "install": "cd server && npm i && cd ../client && npm i",
    "seed": "cd server && npm run seed",
    "build": "cd client && npm run build",
    "heroku-postbuild": "cd client && ng build"
  },
  "dependencies": {
    "@angular/animations": "^16.1.0",
    "@angular-devkit/build-angular": "^16.1.0",
    "@angular/cli": "~16.1.0",
    "@angular/compiler-cli": "^16.1.0",
    "@angular/cdk": "^16.1.3",
    "@angular/common": "^16.1.0",
    "@angular/compiler": "^16.1.0",
    "@angular/core": "^16.1.0",
    "@angular/forms": "^16.1.0",
    "@angular/material": "^16.1.3",
    "@angular/platform-browser": "^16.1.0",
    "@angular/platform-browser-dynamic": "^16.1.0",
    "@angular/router": "^16.1.0",
    "typescript": "~5.1.3",
    "concurrently": "^8.2.0",
    "node": "^18.16.1"
  },
  "engines": {
    "node": "18.16.1",
    "npm": "9.7.1"
  }
}
```

(The angular dependencies used to only be in the client's package.json, but pushing to heroku would give a "ng not found" response. Copying the angular dependencies into the root package.json fixed that problem.)
The client folder's package.json:

```
{
  "name": "curriculum-novum",
  "version": "0.0.0",
  "scripts": {
    "ng": "ng",
    "start": "ng serve",
    "build": "ng build",
    "watch": "ng build --watch --configuration development",
    "test": "ng test"
  },
  "private": true,
  "dependencies": {
    "@angular/animations": "^16.1.0",
    "@angular-devkit/build-angular": "^16.1.0",
    "@angular/cli": "~16.1.0",
    "@angular/compiler-cli": "^16.1.0",
    "@angular/cdk": "^16.1.3",
    "@angular/common": "^16.1.0",
    "@angular/compiler": "^16.1.0",
    "@angular/core": "^16.1.0",
    "@angular/forms": "^16.1.0",
    "@angular/material": "^16.1.3",
    "@angular/platform-browser": "^16.1.0",
    "@angular/platform-browser-dynamic": "^16.1.0",
    "@angular/router": "^16.1.0",
    "@ncstate/sat-popover": "^10.0.0",
    "rxjs": "~7.8.0",
    "tslib": "^2.3.0",
    "zone.js": "~0.13.0"
  },
  "devDependencies": {
    "@angular-devkit/build-angular": "^16.1.0",
    "@types/jasmine": "~4.3.0",
    "jasmine-core": "~4.6.0",
    "karma": "~6.4.0",
    "karma-chrome-launcher": "~3.2.0",
    "karma-coverage": "~2.2.0",
    "karma-jasmine": "~5.1.0",
    "karma-jasmine-html-reporter": "~2.1.0",
    "typescript": "~5.1.3"
  },
  "engines": {
    "node": "18.16.1",
    "npm": "9.7.1"
  }
}
```

And the server folder's package.json:

```
{
  "name": "server",
  "version": "1.0.0",
  "description": "",
  "main": "server.js",
  "scripts": {
    "start": "node server.js",
    "watch": "nodemon",
    "seed": "node seeds/index.js"
  },
  "dependencies": {
    "dotenv": "^16.3.1",
    "express": "^4.18.2",
    "mysql2": "^3.5.0",
    "sequelize": "^6.32.1"
  }
}
```

This is the server.js in the server folder:

```
const express = require('express');
const routes = require('./controller');
const sequelize = require('./config/connection');
const path = require('path');

const PORT = process.env.PORT || 3001;
const app = express();

app.use(express.json());
app.use(express.urlencoded({ extended: false }));
app.use(function (req, res, next) {
  res.header("Access-Control-Allow-Origin", "*");
  res.header("Access-Control-Allow-Methods", "GET,HEAD,OPTIONS,POST,PUT,DELETE");
  res.header("Access-Control-Allow-Headers", "Origin, X-Requested-With, Content-Type, Accept, Authorization");
  next();
});
app.use(routes);
app.use(require('./controller'));

if (process.env.NODE_ENV === "production") {
  app.use(express.static(path.join(__dirname, '../client/dist/curriculum-novum')));
};

app.get('*', (req, res) => {
  console.log("here")
  res.sendFile(path.join(__dirname, '../client/dist/curriculum-novum/index.html'))
});

sequelize.sync({ force: false }).then(() => {
  app.listen(PORT, () => console.log(`Now listening on port ${PORT}`))
});
```

Here are the logs on heroku:
(https://i.stack.imgur.com/ATJ5P.png)
Going to the url says it can't be found with a 404 response. The get requests are still showing up in the logs. Even the tried and true console.log("here") is not showing up leading me to believe that the request isn't even reaching the get function. Please help.